# Moving Code Comments with Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In the HTML code below, I have comments before each LI element and I'd like them to be moved when the LI element is being sorted. Is there a way to link their movements using jQuery UI Sortable? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw1fgm4p/)

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <!--Item 1-->
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <!--Item 2-->
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <!--Item 3-->
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <!--Item 4-->
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <!--Item 5-->
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible?

Comment: Well.. I think I could copy the nodeType 8 before the item being moved and remove it from the DOM of where it previously was and insert it before the new LI position, right? I was just hoping there's an easier way, since I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is also trying to accomplish this, I was able to do it with this bit of code:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <!--Item 1-->
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <!--Item 2-->
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <!--Item 3-->
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <!--Item 4-->
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <!--Item 5-->
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

var theComment;
$("#sortable").sortable({
  items: '> li',
  start : function(e, ui) {
     theComment = ui.item.context.previousSibling;
  },
  update: function(e, ui){
    if (ui.item.context.previousSibling.nodeType === 8) {
      ui.item.insertBefore(ui.item.context.previousSibling);
   } else if (ui.item.context.previousSibling.nodeType === 1) {
     ui.item.insertAfter(ui.item.context.previousSibling);
   }
     ui.item.before(theComment);
   }
});
```

One thing I should point out is that my code is minified, so `.previousSibling` isn't showing line breaks or indents. If your code isn't minified, this code won't work for you.
[JSFiddle Minified HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/pw1fgm4p/1/)

Update:
This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw1fgm4p/2/) should work even if your code isn't minified.